# How to add a counter based on dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server query that yields the following data. `IdCx` will always have the same `FecCx`.

| IdCx | FecCx | FecTest | Resultado |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2023-01-04 17:00:00 | 2023-01-02 12:00:00 | 0.3 |
| 1234 | 2023-01-04 17:00:00 | 2023-01-03 17:00:00 | 0.4 |
| 1234 | 2023-01-04 17:00:00 | 2023-01-04 19:00:00 | 0.4 |
| 1234 | 2023-01-04 17:00:00 | 2023-01-04 23:00:00 | 0.4 |
| 1234 | 2023-01-04 17:00:00 | 2023-01-05 05:00:00 | 0.6 |

For each `IdCx`, I require to add a chronologically ordered index based on whether `FecTest` occurred before of after `FecCx`. If it occurred before, that row number should should increase negatively. If `FecTest` occurred after `FecCx`, the row number should increase positively

| IdCx | FecCx | FecTest | Resultado | Order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2023-01-04 17:00:00 | 2023-01-02 12:00:00 | 0.3 | -2 |
| 1234 | 2023-01-04 17:00:00 | 2023-01-03 17:00:00 | 0.4 | -1 |
| 1234 | 2023-01-04 17:00:00 | 2023-01-04 19:00:00 | 0.4 | 1 |
| 1234 | 2023-01-04 17:00:00 | 2023-01-04 23:00:00 | 0.4 | 2 |
| 1234 | 2023-01-04 17:00:00 | 2023-01-05 05:00:00 | 0.6 | 3 |

Comment: What if it exactly matched?

Comment: It could be a possibility but in real data chances are low due to use of seconds. Also, process bases on the fact that Test and Cx will never occur at the same time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you can achieve this with `ROW_NUMBER` and a (couple) `CASE` expressions:

```sql
SELECT IdCx,
       FecCx,
       FecTest,
       Resultado,
       CASE WHEN FecTest > FecCx THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IdCx, CASE WHEN FecTest > FecCx THEN 1 END ORDER BY FecTest)
            ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IdCx, CASE WHEN FecTest > FecCx THEN 1 END ORDER BY FecTest DESC) * -1 END AS RN
FROM (VALUES(1234,CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2023-01-04 17:00:00'),CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2023-01-02 12:00:00'),0.3),
            (1234,CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2023-01-04 17:00:00'),CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2023-01-03 17:00:00'),0.4),
            (1234,CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2023-01-04 17:00:00'),CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2023-01-04 19:00:00'),0.4),
            (1234,CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2023-01-04 17:00:00'),CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2023-01-04 23:00:00'),0.4),
            (1234,CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2023-01-04 17:00:00'),CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2023-01-05 05:00:00'),0.6))V(IdCx,FecCx,FecTest,Resultado)
ORDER BY IdCx,
         FecTest;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here how to do it using `row_number()` and `union all` :

```
select IdCx, FecCx, FecTest, Resultado, row_number() over (order by FecTest desc) * -1 as [Order]
from mytable
where FecTest <= FecCx
union all
select IdCx, FecCx, FecTest, Resultado, row_number() over (order by FecTest)
from mytable
where FecTest > FecCx;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/syp4_oDm)

Comment: The `UNION` feels like unneccessary; you aren't going to get any rows that are identical, so the implicit `DISTINCT` is going to be a pointless expense.

Comment: @ThomA That's correct .. I have edited my answer

Comment: I think this is the better answer, it is likely more efficient than using a custom ordering.